# The thousand character classic

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, unicode

## Background

The Thousand Character Classic is a chinese poem written around the 4th Century CE in China, and memorized by large populations since then. The name comes from not only its length, but its number of characters: each character occurs only once in the text. It is commonly used to teach children chinese characters, and also, because of its commonness, as a means of enumerating the 1000 characters in the text.

## The challenge

Here is a copy of the Thousand Character Classic, gotten from Wikipedia.

[The Thousand Character Classic](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/eaglgenes101/a4d111602192e51a1f5ca2f630fee8b5/raw/4c30e332eb2d4b1a7fd3ee8f0dbbe0c29c723424/gistfile1.txt)

Reproduce the entirety of the Thousand Character Classic in either UTF-8 or UTF-16, including punctuation, newlines, and heading numbers. Punctuation can be halfwidth or fullwidth, and the trailing newline is optional.

For those that want to analyze the unicode text for patterns, I've provided hexdumps of both encodings.

[utf-8](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/eaglgenes101/0fe04803dccc0e6ee200471c9ca1738e/raw/f879288c705f6c7feb37ded3112cc6a10f0646be/gistfile1.txt)

[utf-16](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/eaglgenes101/cadf59d69c27dacd95151a79a33bb377/raw/e565c92bbb387d2cbf0e76bba63e30ad3ff07079/gistfile1.txt)

## Rules

Because of the size of the text to reproduce, you may optionally supply a file for your submission to use as input. If this is done, add the byte length of the input file to the byte length of your code.

Otherwise, this is a standard issue code golf challenge, so standard loopholes apply, and shortest submission wins.

Comment: Your link is probably encoded in something other than Unicode.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer It's in UTF-8.

Comment: Chrome isn't able to correctly infer a character encoding.  I had to use a plugin to force UTF-8, as the option as apparently been removed(!?)

Comment: Can you post an english translation.

Comment: Also... you may optionally supply a file...? Groovy: `{it.text}` where it is a file containing the 1,000 line classic.

Comment: File length is added to code length in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 2526 bytes

```
00000000: 2dd4 47c2 82cc 9680 e1f9 b78a de42 e7ed  -.G..........B..
00000010: 898a 808a 3921 28e6 0ca8 1830 e162 9a13  ....9!(....0.b..
00000020: 6ad4 5bb8 50fe e3e7 bc86 4aff fe07 8b2d  j.[.P.....J....-
00000030: 3847 aa15 c5ab f0ff ef2a f81a f816 5e76  8G.......*....^v
00000040: 6cb6 fe2f 97ff b73f ec2f d1d1 c9d6 7190  l../...?./....q.
00000050: 39c7 47f0 bfa0 f7e1 7d95 0e41 2b89 4b38  9.G.....}..A+.K8
00000060: 6c42 9c4b 9dd6 15ec dca0 74e0 7e5d bae8  lB.K......t.~]..
00000070: d5c5 6280 7a03 bd73 ea10 57a0 99e7 dd57  ..b.z..s..W....W
00000080: 589f 9fdb 67b1 39b2 7611 f626 75e1 9ce9  X...g.9.v..&u...
00000090: daa0 fc53 38ce cfb5 2675 5cf1 ece3 f192  ...S8...&u\.....
000000a0: 3ad5 0cd0 9e70 69c2 792a 1dca 265b 2edc  :....pi.y*..&[..
000000b0: 37a2 dfcd bc3e a1cd 0916 0ea8 8674 1c3b  7....>.......t.;
000000c0: 5437 7154 43f7 983a d71d a199 5c5e c2da  T7qTC..:....\^..
000000d0: f9f9 f50e ad08 cf21 dea7 a98b 531f 3f36  .......!....S.?6
000000e0: c51f fa76 a4ff c79f 884d 88f6 a4ec 211a  ...v.....M....!.
000000f0: 6513 e112 fc41 f27c d250 9313 b0ae 807e  e....A.|.P.....~
00000100: c39e 065e 3ff5 e451 40c7 e4e9 9ce7 a174  ...^?..Q@......t
00000110: ac6d 928f c97e 1b9c 4aea e818 6c8d 8575  .m...~..J...l..u
00000120: 834e 433a bc3b 786c 26ef 067d 76a9 4373  .NC:.;xl&..}v.Cs
00000130: 43d6 1bfd 3b3e 829f 8f1a e88c a05b 174a  C...;>.......[.J
00000140: 3bf3 711e 2b27 7884 b49f 48c7 a2cd f9b3  ;.q.+'x...H.....
00000150: 78d5 c4aa 973a 6bf3 e45d 47bd 4671 55ba  x....:k..]G.FqU.
00000160: 501a 22af 2551 4eec 3b72 0535 0edb e845  P.".%QN.;r.5...E
00000170: 54ab fc3c bc88 3004 6743 fb47 e6d6 47ac  T..<..0.gC.G..G.
00000180: 5b62 eec2 e422 1daa 3d9e edd9 34d0 d9a4  [b..."..=...4...
00000190: cee1 05ea 656e 1cb0 f790 fe9f 7fdc aea0  ....en..........
000001a0: b7e0 e75e ecfd 7402 6c1b 16eb e4d9 8128  ...^..t.l......(
000001b0: 9213 a878 5870 c578 2216 e5d4 f9a4 6377  ...xXp.x".....cw
000001c0: 8641 0ef2 77e9 b00c 51ed f279 4c57 2775  .A..w...Q..yLW'u
000001d0: eadc b1ab a361 b211 4827 7729 941a 7c55  .....a..H'w)..|U
000001e0: ec3c e419 ea73 e1c3 b53d 7c07 3fff 7478  .<...s...=|.?.tx
000001f0: afc1 e74d ae97 ba18 4d51 29c0 fd24 ba77  ...M....MQ)..$.w
00000200: e9c9 779a 7cbe 500f 7855 ca7a 6b83 87b3  ..w.|.P.xU.zk...
00000210: b0e7 42ab 4b87 d906 f367 ba9e d16d a7ce  ..B.K....g...m..
00000220: db2d fb43 8a3b 1497 a5a3 15f0 b44a 378f  .-.C.;.......J7.
00000230: c359 d6ab 15f8 5e93 8fc3 4a4f 3ac4 7778  .Y....^...JO:.wx
00000240: 3da1 61d2 be92 f967 46fb b4d8 a037 974e  =.a....gF....7.N
00000250: db27 1fef 900f 5939 a7ce 960d 933c 7d5b  .'....Y9.....<}[
00000260: ac7c 7ebe 32c1 9e60 614a 5b33 755a d5e9  .|~.2..`aJ[3uZ..
00000270: 3e87 5e11 d59b 7438 3ea9 b516 a331 04b7  >.^...t8>....1..
00000280: d421 8884 75c4 4140 fb9f 73a8 917e 4b9e  .!..u.A@..s..~K.
00000290: 1568 d8a9 a37d 84e1 8575 0dbb 07e9 e08d  .h...}...u......
000002a0: a87b a3bd 07e5 cce1 3b01 4323 7b0a cd8f  .{......;.C#{...
000002b0: 74d6 3678 3fc1 69c9 bd62 e60b 8b75 1d9f  t.6x?.i..b...u..
000002c0: 7bd0 cad2 93f7 9b07 1ef6 02b1 da64 beca  {............d..
000002d0: e328 4e1e 15b2 6de9 701f e155 4922 1395  .(N...m.p..UI"..
000002e0: 2075 bc5f 312e 42bd 8783 c9cf fd07 7a33   u._1.B.......z3
000002f0: ae2c 3137 4a9d 3739 8e3d f00d f087 d229  .,17J.79.=.....)
00000300: 5880 3ee2 dd84 e25a d6ab 35ba e6c1 7792  X.>....Z..5...w.
00000310: d742 3aae 7c5c 7a68 e4c0 7d66 7ddf a0ce  .B:.|\zh..}f}...
00000320: 908a 53da bbd2 c18b a0b8 23eb 95bc ba59  ..S.......#....Y
00000330: df19 b172 8778 8c9d ef3f 3e48 5e4b ea0c  ...r.x...?>H^K..
00000340: 703e 491d 6a2f ce55 c92e f376 221d 3779  p>I.j/.U...v".7y
00000350: f4cb 7cbe 70b8 90eb ef83 be84 6319 cca6  ..|.p.......c...
00000360: f424 2a43 ab9a 4415 1aad e4fa eca1 7382  .$*C..D.......s.
00000370: ed4a 0c37 d261 d183 7a1f f22a 6fda 99ab  .J.7.a..z..*o...
00000380: 4b58 1a18 9850 cc49 e77d 04eb 66f2 0ea0  KX...P.I.}..f...
00000390: 2e6f 60f5 065e 0383 0ea8 2de9 e075 50bb  .o`..^....-..uP.
000003a0: 835a 84b7 9bf5 8d2a 1ee7 2237 c7c9 437a  .Z.....*.."7..Cz
000003b0: f25c 40bd 82e5 2ee8 a5cc 758d e61b f22f  .\@.......u..../
000003c0: bcaa fffc a5a0 aa8b e109 0baf d445 6e82  .............En.
000003d0: 8729 bcfb c29e 49a7 2047 f116 5e86 c8e5  .)....I. G..^...
000003e0: 329f da78 b6a1 ba63 6b2d 1d73 6b31 72b0  2..x...ck-.sk1r.
000003f0: a08a 5c24 cf47 012a 5d5a 8ea9 7796 0ebe  ..\$.G.*]Z..w...
00000400: 4e8e 0bdf 3ebe bef2 f31b 646c b158 a7f5  N...>.....dl.X..
00000410: ebe7 1315 ab8a b055 6c9b 59bf fc90 7e65  .......Ul.Y...~e
00000420: 6d47 d1cf ffeb 4f14 3e22 dfe4 7a00 8b7a  mG....O.>"..z..z
00000430: b643 a313 2fbf c9b3 9a3c 7f27 940b 5591  .C../....<.'..U.
00000440: b7c4 6886 173b f3ab 8f91 87ed 21de 34e9  ..h..;......!.4.
00000450: e0fb e87f c95e 8882 92f9 a6cd eb9c 98db  .....^..........
00000460: 623b fcb9 d383 604f ab0f 9951 ead4 ddc3  b;....`O...Q....
00000470: 679b bcd2 4fd4 a527 91c5 ba09 7913 ba6e  g...O..'....y..n
00000480: e69d 3344 211c 4d5c 3ea4 73be 44de 9537  ..3D!.M\>.s.D..7
00000490: 1e44 f205 79b7 a9e9 42e3 4107 4b3a 989a  .D..y...B.A.K:..
000004a0: 18d6 e862 0a4b dea0 b7c2 1f83 7a4d 1cb8  ...b.K......zM..
000004b0: 3faf 8722 3784 d71c d475 e6f7 9550 3a68  ?.."7....u...P:h
000004c0: 7c71 5093 8efd 99b0 4b30 0b41 8d52 4f9e  |qP.....K0.A.RO.
000004d0: 2b56 8614 2fb8 72fa f9c8 a1cd 5798 b118  +V../.r.....W...
000004e0: 668e ef12 da11 cc15 bab5 a5c3 d3a1 5885  f.............X.
000004f0: a346 76e6 7c0f 92ef 04d7 0d30 bfd2 51bf  .Fv.|......0..Q.
00000500: c151 0175 4fd1 3c75 f06f 745d 8159 00f5  .Q.uO.<u.ot].Y..
00000510: 2a5d ec07 509a 086b c7ef 55ea 62ab f227  *]..P..k..U.b..'
00000520: 8fd5 809e 6de9 49d4 a374 4362 1d82 6aea  ....m.I..tCb..j.
00000530: fc2a 8b75 97f3 4b7e 77a5 93d7 83b2 cbd5  .*.u..K~w.......
00000540: 3c04 590f 9516 cd9a a0bf 4479 f0f3 f90b  <.Y.......Dy....
00000550: 9fbb e45d 86e3 23f5 e4d3 402b 2f06 5f9e  ...]..#...@+/._.
00000560: 4ea5 c3b2 08be 8af6 590c 9cac 8f7d ecaf  N.......Y....}..
00000570: c03b 92e6 4ac7 691b d403 54a7 d0d0 53c7  .;..J.i...T...S.
00000580: af0b ef13 1a37 c8c7 d2e9 f604 7b8c ef19  .....7......{...
00000590: 1626 a9f3 6e87 4517 bd55 1229 d293 6f39  .&..n.E..U.)..o9
000005a0: 79e4 2128 41e5 2b6f e810 e67b 083a 10ac  y.!(A.+o...{.:..
000005b0: a5a3 65e0 7288 f645 3872 fd6e 96f0 ea60  ..e.r..E8r.n...`
000005c0: 1f71 bb97 0e8a 2672 1d7c a96c cd32 8f1a  .q....&r.|.l.2..
000005d0: e0b8 e814 c876 a527 9fae 50ae 7429 62d8  .....v.'..P.t)b.
000005e0: 4d5d b86d 7897 49dd 82de 94ce d73b 7d57  M].mx.I......;}W
000005f0: 62d2 2763 2dcf d786 5f26 3a39 3ac7 d2c1  b.'c-..._&:9:...
00000600: 9fc3 46c1 b385 ef49 d6af 42f6 3e49 f410  ..F....I..B.>I..
00000610: a396 f4e4 3182 fb98 560f be4f b3de 8a45  ....1...V..O...E
00000620: 614a eb15 3c6e d2e1 1c82 dfc7 f008 e753  aJ..<n.........S
00000630: e6ab 5d12 bd92 6733 797a d285 ad88 5e8e  ..]...g3yz....^.
00000640: 2e7b 988e 5317 f698 3a47 be2e c0ad 49c7  .{..S...:G....I.
00000650: 4109 4f13 9acd c90d 3337 54a1 d5f0 3286  A.O.....37T...2.
00000660: 7f7a b427 4299 d0ed 2bf2 7aea 70de c279  .z.'B...+.z.p..y
00000670: 8fa3 104a 4be9 fffd 87e7 173a 07ec bd39  ...JK......:...9
00000680: 3ecb 1360 71f5 4c9b 376d a7ff ecc0 8ddf  >..`q.L.7m......
00000690: 0698 7dea 8e52 47bd c9fd 9178 99b4 b94b  ..}..RG....x...K
000006a0: a78d 4a25 97cf 33ec 1d65 1f71 3816 2f47  ..J%..3..e.q8./G
000006b0: 58ae 74f0 5c7e bdb0 bba2 cb24 f3fa 5978  X.t.\~.....$..Yx
000006c0: 435a 1b64 5f7e febc c123 4e22 0f9e 91ec  CZ.d_~...#N"....
000006d0: c77c b0f8 f0c0 6e57 3a2b 25e1 8610 b8d4  .|....nW:+%.....
000006e0: 28a5 2e9a 2d3e 5739 deb0 71fe f9f9 03b5  (...->W9..q.....
000006f0: 250c 0caa de65 6f80 7aa3 651f 17a6 7472  %....eo.z.e...tr
00000700: 147e 1ed8 abf3 6e9a 7970 85d9 18cb 7d5c  .~....n.yp....}\
00000710: 5ea5 a35f e2f8 c4df 262a cbd4 71dc a761  ^.._....&*..q..a
00000720: 051e 1198 a174 50b7 d4ab f3aa 825b 3775  .....tP......[7u
00000730: 5ecf e95a e4dd 51e4 ded2 e932 8393 2a7a  ^..Z..Q....2..*z
00000740: 2db6 ba59 7f36 c46b 0041 1e82 a574 3ce5  -..Y.6.k.A...t<.
00000750: a1be 8063 85f7 bdcc bb73 547d 9133 8562  ...c.....sT}.3.b
00000760: fdfc 3087 659d 2e81 50e6 99ab 6f3e 8cd0  ..0.e...P...o>..
00000770: 9b62 c5fe 7934 61f3 4ec3 227a f2ff 392d  .b..y4a.N."z..9-
00000780: ae7d b0fc c1d9 e8e7 630d 4777 b486 f49d  .}......c.Gw....
00000790: 64fd 6c8d d306 0f17 a055 a40b 2bc4 c903  d.l......U..+...
000007a0: d61d fa86 a973 e3c3 4d43 cc8b d8e8 49c7  .....s..MC....I.
000007b0: 2812 d798 cc8d 502a a983 56c5 e696 aea1  (.....P*..V.....
000007c0: 708a d2ff e78f 731f f673 54db 4294 972b  p.....s..sT.B..+
000007d0: d826 db07 bb4c fee9 9f33 d8e6 f70d 3b11  .&...L...3....;.
000007e0: 75eb 999f 0e9c 0b61 3c27 a324 1dd4 3b97  u......a<'.$..;.
000007f0: 42b1 6888 7990 ba50 b650 9f83 aab2 1a49  B.h.y..P.P.....I
00000800: 17f3 8f98 efa9 f000 ff98 f97c 0635 8f42  ...........|.5.B
00000810: 97c2 8974 5eed 501f 6257 65bd 9c3a e714  ...t^.P.bWe..:..
00000820: 3836 a97b a470 2d1d 5631 c453 8a62 bac8  86.{.p-.V1.S.b..
00000830: 1d8e 55b8 c710 dd51 ff4a a78b 8e86 064e  ..U....Q.J.....N
00000840: 1b3f 9dd4 4539 479a 476a 8bd4 aa74 b446  .?..E9G.Gj...t.F
00000850: e44c 60d1 85a0 913a f74d f24c 3e4d e159  .L`....:.M.L>M.Y
00000860: 960e ef15 7a55 a1b6 c0bf a48e b525 8e02  ....zU.......%..
00000870: d60d 5e5f a493 1ba0 5111 9336 dfc2 ccf3  ..^_....Q..6....
00000880: 2a9f f649 d481 e75d 3aec a710 57a1 3fa7  *..I...]:...W.?.
00000890: 6735 755a 7ab4 cc51 6104 83be 74da 7cc4  g5uZz..Qa...t.|.
000008a0: d482 9289 1547 f643 d4de a834 b070 fbb9  .....G.C...4.p..
000008b0: 5f21 a345 c729 af94 d4c5 744d 5e07 822d  _!.E.)....tM^..-
000008c0: 6f43 e962 17c1 7886 8510 af97 d4c1 bd53  oC.b..x........S
000008d0: e924 a603 bcbd 7fbe 9d89 4d4c e519 198f  .$........ML....
000008e0: ac5f 7bfc 34f9 a68a ed42 3aef 54ec 1d38  ._{.4....B:.T..8
000008f0: 2c93 2dbf dfec 9279 86ba 9d3c a7d2 fff7  ,.-....y...<....
00000900: 0fa2 021c 8b50 1826 91bc a357 8d1a 1731  .....P.&...W...1
00000910: f061 10a4 137f a81c c82b 416e 4f17 2b65  .a.......+AnO.+e
00000920: a18f e1be 4e5e 2fa1 cd33 165a 852e 36e8  ....N^/..3.Z..6.
00000930: dbe4 db4f 99f6 231a 9692 4f08 2b4b d681  ...O..#...O.+K..
00000940: 8dbd 0fde 9bb0 964f fc7d 29a6 4758 9974  .......O.}).GX.t
00000950: 6866 0c8f 0bb9 330c ea90 3fa4 8cf6 0a87  hf....3...?.....
00000960: 063a 7db4 9d8c a9f5 a5d6 1cb5 087b d38c  .:}..........{..
00000970: ad95 f08a d43a 92ba ce18 ab1a f776 c9d7  .....:.......v..
00000980: a7a5 93f1 31a2 5b1d 1a06 943d 59bb 5bf4  ....1.[....=Y.[.
00000990: 96f0 ee8a c920 e5e4 1b24 af23 bcca f072  ..... ...$.#...r
000009a0: 653d 7221 ba91 ebc0 b328 4fd6 00e2 328d  e=r!.....(O...2.
000009b0: 5fe4 3c33 066f 21ac 0a04 5356 c629 6371  _.<3.o!...SV.)cq
000009c0: c82d 8b3c 8377 c38c f990 e7dd 18ca 5bce  .-.<.w........[.
000009d0: a929 53d1 80b6 913c 6ac9 c34d f95f       .)S....<j..M._
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVppu1U10v3Or4i0isBL3JmTC0IjKi3IYCtiM5rRbgURZBb4675rZe9zLt33efoA7d11kkrVGiq7PCvlQf/52cO//lq2nwOhW7PChqpF1LWK5OMiuhpJlBCzaN1q0UNvQpySF@X@53Mpj6wRFGLEhF@NCz5M0kro2L1Yao5CRcNoXouUlRGCj6YPPuEfiyz7GBoxfMY6XClRuGV00U0PotTohc1jiNGXIGLRWMcv8ra8PhdxiR@nthgGMUy0QeSsnKguFzEWPNmHzmJENT@8cD14IeJuKyf4ce/5FsNyHbV4fJ0eIgU8XoJBjIp/NtWUqKl5EVRahHgg5ad4@Nz8lI93e3FcR6oBOR2LKCMvYoSuRGjJiaVbpKfEJGwxUYi05fStlOdPystxi@HnOpD5VG0RqeE7letVtIpowXZ8dNdEyR0xHnwuL6@beSrf3d3nNCBGc9UJr3GiIS9GlBaM6FktwuHfIiWkuDUXeC5FvpbyDylvMtDNLUZEDBcTUjFaET4Uha0VLYJXSgyvkQqHraXakxA/4sGfZZLPpfz4mdyvI3EdmVmozuCEahd1FCe0D064OhSy240YKulZH99FyQB35o62GJk5zQ35qw3r7mERPqFiQ8LZKmQF0VwRurcqxAEf/P0/8hXO9uPb@xiFMULWoo2K1FXTRVb425JQFUtHsUYfrFDVFCECY5yVu7Se3mJU5sOagApwaBozgkjRoEuCaoiWEjbksD/dshDfh8ffX5ByLufOvf06GmKMhP4absES2hKRDzRN6xm1m2IRzqghzDB@7Rf8fMCP7@Q5v8XoiFEdfmtkVHO2qNMacEwx2oaPwf8P5aIVqp4xns8oV9ZQW4zBGnNoyq6UxuGgMIcOqDHtkGKD/1CW3NHVoQvR@eh5@WZrvHdHttbnOkzqYvHYthnDiW6dEnZB/XeLqkBpYFcKieU67p2T8tu/b1ndYhA/cvVNJB2xjYSvUyVVtH3PokcV0QkRu3IoFyEf8tvXzkf/PdtiED@isR1HgtMoPMIQPRLg@8DaQkPFZvScCcSgqxcO5OmXDz5G2z2XF/7YYhA/rGGnldGEKaiPqJnTobiOWEVeUGPYCnKKc5Wnd/VxW17aYhA/TBkG9aE6@lyjUnAmolgEshFJyRolN1LBOk4DM04ee4kA/3iv1hXxI0TUerU5A4OwIc@QSGwDphR8@KCEcwXr4NPy4Fcp716UXz2@sYtB/HAL1q11HkI7HklHQZgStFicIRChoXu0yOl1eVR@9O1VefqJdIj25RYjzFonilZTicRRGCAkUMCiWwuAtntky4aMnvteyjOE9J8vENAu7tYx8aMA/fHl@LBao1uxK9NQM721JIxFQ7eUUR@3wQdYivwMf9jDfBA/agfKLA4F4Z1HfdRCUAUIj47EhoG2R7Usa7/03w5paotB/CgBsNmBV8AbHHCwi0ZlKZyo70iFxWKi0nGtUzb9gzXEJ1sM4gfIzYgcAzgqAoOqw9@0Bn4AjS2OFdvwJkw8lS9//F2@PDpD1BdbDOJH9Oi0BawkQkCDFKCKcAoEi@5DiSKm0GHW@nkpX@Dpb6V89c3NY7taJ370jB0XhcPJxitR0OgoL1Zb0Og5i5MP1bkNPzIq7NiL41K@ubHFIH50HivoKCEaaQHAJ4ozyEwF1aKXkVgbmA@cLJlBfvYGZPf05RaD@JFHBXwHgE7uCXSd0a22odp0qjicplH6ecvHRJ8r32IZH8otH5r40VNNWHfikktH2S744ojF1xxY@tGIGMrUDi8mAL28IV//uj9bTfwoC1DGauTDlghOSwso3HiuCIXWFNAlBxCPoHCZZPkz/vdwH4P40SguUNf4ugz8UBYbyi4bMC953KLtTQBCCXlKXpCntwK7FHYxzMRCl0TzWAceQpH0hGjoH4CZBaTnarHTmdN/ybXM5KVrB/LFllM98aNlJbxqWpQOShwJ27B@FCyhRWAQ2CdBAgjxGQ8WO/mKn0Fe3WK4dS9BqAHwS0ynSyatCUh@AdAanHxoADMhj/Hhf6W5lzNvb28x/MRkkEHoOBKjccqpe5CuQhZcMQA450B7jrwv37yTWsqf8qXb5tmtfU6JH6bjNKAQwG4uAZMtNI/pQOLi0DTZGHSCLaiPszMXT@OEVLWPQfxoFuQYiaLBIX8WIItjYtsbcHZS4AtbEs8WLPlMnv/7LNZ3l3cxiB/K@ShaxBdnAzKIFnAyCWVppYiFfdgXkIyQ/17FmHz2Pn5o4gfanu0G/MXvozorYpiyoPGMRj5AlqK2WR9/rs@elhf@9udhDOIHOsUL1CWywM7xLP3SiI9@KZC3WJFq2Jp4Kv3Lc/I/lGVzLVsM4gcYAMiTUR9p6o@CblUdlI@vQJ6zR891KCLxp3zvp@1jTPwwADokAVDqIOd8QwICWhoogMaziThtEvHjk6uzUX6X8sbXR/cxiB96wWpLdahrpXEGGpkBMhpQeIUwaVhWwAkLIZ7J@4qGYf68NluMiR9dg5QUStrmBNINqNPYgUEDOgkf7GWtWWP/p8IlGdIkBymPH9kk/9SnkLemdwi7hiLpmoXJFjRkyA6IJ7po6tNZXahQ0tyLbS@G@NECtLbJkDuATVR9Rrl0CwgLzUPjtjbQeBM/Pj@Qb@68RpW8HW/3Z2uIH4n2B/gJ/VFwOFVByeUFdkYb8EtyBYidHfcCJbf@/G023xaD@NGggoHrIOlImIhwG/AvMCCmW8IJzABork48fSJJ/ufO/uPe5f06iB9hgXKxCYLUZ7iW2gmlCSc0DLQi2Ip5BtOI389@LX/5VN6gPjwqw6stBvFj2FpWOA7cQVrIkANnWyAZQHFYZa156tM3rI2V5Q7z4WcMoL/OwNNcAO7WwpWpnLEhO3AuFSgXTKTm//AE5NQXW5Q/djGIH70Bb5ZqWAbguQY7icOh7oWwEX4g2Sll4hiKg3AID3Pi0eE6iB@2OPhQMlOKULa1WjR7AAosFrvyHkS8TO1wmQbmuvya/T8OYxA/dPdD@AXydgpdBDarZdBtQgedzFK4jkc/rbAOkpDPru9i5KlPUZiRaJcKAsVG69LBW1pjfwDbqU@p12/tnOlR2JALr7cYxI@hUZ12YadpYJDu8H/ZwbUHB/TqHmoGmSEG3dlU9gpkn24xiB@lQoCB3SvZbYFbRp12tSSxFGjFZiEJfY967z3Wny9/2@2F@BEpMwpsHKxOYrXBuugFknCoabHh2mvsxI/jfPhrKS6uadliED8MxXXLKPPiUQslewO2BwcrulRfwA0BoCkEuIWVXn89Jf/4VT3ZxZj4MXuuotDqwLfDCOCfjXkmyaDK6ezK5P07H0KWnrh7a9VURza7z/roESdaGpsMv1qozIZBJr31FFmonhxwYOLq3hK2B/LHfQziBx4ECBtUeC5YUVnQc76C8cB6KNaaaNi92@f0xoMpAN71LcacfzTsoCli50Bh2qEsVqTpV7ulf19IEKiPh3NkcE2ePTrrfasPS/wonu1G76ZHoZmCbkqZbA9xCV0IknEuKazjwjq8gLaDAtj5BmunTgbL@ogjVAE6aBj0Vxx4KHIKBPiAILCT90mWp3cG1e5iED/6MuguApeAfgF7g600PG/2sD@d9i7FVrZ83PtfvW7n/EPz22uBoGK7@QUKKheomZQgMDunRa1BWoky1/DTtVUq72MQP3zAGZQKOLYDv58ds6AqeCuj4EOiyc0wFOLnmdFVDb2S8rctBvGjezKTsZZ2ulLeVmoYHIlBuViLfCRnpsY1X3wgr9w5CwwDmoUtxtQfHY8PvTh8Z6HLR/6s7tCFCjRpCzxeiom9/8X8frDleXn5YL8X4oeK0A7oLMBVBg80Ylbh2E6NiYoQ4fBFq38pu4nQ6yv7GHP@MdDiaF5NKWs5toDft0Av4Bsy44CPhtwnzq3gs8LH9YN/bzGm/qh0nwuVbYePShAg3MGCHoKxgXFlsqnH3jxehwWXF2zmn9d26yB@6OI8jBAqHHUa0edghJFqXCcyLiSAggJii5M/sE6fzDg3D8@W@OE9@rYPhQbJEJi1Kh5rcQREg5oBpkAaoOfGfwHZj7sYEz@MBb377ml6UFma4wLbgCTNcHaHwnGqEE@/eg6mk@vcEmV2ZBv1UfMrlCPssmONQRJW/G0snu4Jhj0qUP5C5hB47Nk1eeaZfPT0Ltt/i0H80Bm/2um7kFgwXvRA1oDFuOl5aWyA66ixE3dJUfJX9iyk4bEtxpx/jAZWWZD5KedsYsGbwDGVp@1GC3qOVGbPPQQmy6cXEOKX3TqIH6MCQKcMTWGgOuGZgaIZ/zRISjTQirU07uUEK@Pyuxf/1bdu@pe6WOAe00mRX2HuqYMGWgWqYyyIOxKASJxZTRB@vnj1XgziRxqlrAOP6NEl2szBUsOKIHJRM7B3btYYHru76qi/n/xU3t/F8BPXse7KJS8RjRozJDKWBeSpuSJbgRlHO0xcn0JsG8RuMYgfFbTLquAQugboddBCs4vhYARgvUCJOxw41nGaMynodfn9nNRtMeL0yAvFE6BGZRI9p0BN44QGIA1qPlb@17RhYVjXcugb3MQPjlpzQuo8HZV1Cta2gWQU1XHTaEY/DGN8DPCSX7I8wLyP0haD@BFSJ4RR@Ctqh4IS7VEt6H0Ym4VjTLVwlvNKfvDJeXny0VzGHoMc8WP6YSgg0JmOETuAWDDAE8h9T3MJo9yzn3OYzq79Mj6RnMb8tMUgfqgB/CgF7nrpkYPbwOqE18wJfFub0evITcjHzMTHT9B4D2gwtxjTv1CVYvHg/cgB6MT1kTk9oIa3SIrXLW45fU5cvy6fHi@7GMQPAHkTJfomQsRi0C9UVURzC6XfyH1hzsav3JUPX7Jfpql7u83G3ZyfaiCEDlAuuoG4W4gsTJyVyTgNk@dRw4CIIo9VKEJ5/@ODdLA/W7/MWud8gDalGMBVH3aOENAvGhUL4Y9KAU1wL1@tYgrsAOm@izHnpwZKZ1gcsFHoc9hjuAXoVagZsGYxjfVvN/0Bey1/mHS3m/X5qT/o7Tv0DjoYh4kSVSCUOOflgYYscnoGvs2XIBsOZ2zfbTHM5EoglWvA5NJguXzgpCBBtDSNreUWaWLi7Nu7HF2YV69XAbDFsFNroxxTxG85gzIfHnsxGdqodJiYusBB2DR77s/VSR1cXNOyxSB@WOpZy55LGYQC/UUKR/ehbzmLQJ3CAcO/nJ9pAHMH9q3exSB@hIF1F6s5WEo4koXqp3BsRxQNS@Ocnz4KIuwY3e1J/AVeaPNRPkxM5vwI/A0oZcePQY9Mrcix7hI6BGYza@9f2iib5bH1rY9zhgIvpmCpRFCAQUtZCSfHiRZvtypcaqRBFdCmPz2W38jw8H1M9sSPhUkMkAzgbPIzp8g1kb0V9Dco3IqS7NRjAMB/zoRSc1/eYsz5R4DFsFmTG1DrButC30LUzoY2vFvTFOGIcekjZJQQ8DjKTy9uMcr06rM9kX4HesPeoR1KyWQVaHgYXcj3xPnYj/KpvPNubuNDIPM2H/N1zuih7xWULjoNMaCVgRpKo4colhfSQlJYm7hwS7b7jPG3q0ffywfxowbgDbQkIGxB/nxHn5tMauF1FoQJlhUb7ywm6f928@DkR@/ndM4/YqYDA7vpBsftOLtovcxj6usND9gDPcfbzlNnbya5AtouBvFDO/DRQkPWaA/8mDd1E2NhclWAxQ4W@Cjmt/dHqDDexDx9cmS74iOeWt6YdM4GyyQITlJTQFW4lqAa68QxzgxmPn@Tr6Zhf3tni0H8cOTKbBzqSSMp1aKeNGQH2R4cpThfDzDgAlL9/kTlE3M3eYtB/ICSwTpUiut1D/wwwG/eHxjsL2rHsg07D/T0@nZ3Era5djBzHaisnnDAYPvGsThEagfG9kRaMOA5zakw13Frk/tghhObBwoTP1rx66Ql8AqtWmgp2jTkCGCWHdZmKr3pKVK@h5Y6z/Wc2c4lED@yomIApiGJg1QLi11KIO8HNo3hf/CrR67r2OL7tyj5ssWY8w/gpjAcYXkHB6FBV0gKpMScWICu8Q28zRSUlH2OHsDYZ3f1EYgfiXcn1aGeQjJwZYqirIMvIAahmDUAwCTeiVMMvrJZXpVHgahpuxMPU390LBm1zi5BQQB@sSKz8C4pYGs2kjkSY7zdzXEuvjis00D88JC26zUcdDE89QAwZ5rcTEupCxwjMBbc0Ha3JjeIh/sYxI/mVRMjRwoZ3jcY0l6DX601QlXFHne4vo6B5JUL7@N6KLPnKPdpDyoX4xaUaE6wP85XmhiwIMBZrT2HjJ6YTHe4julfODNoTF3nOD/wsnX4ebZwpMB6C4ADFIjfdwv543tOL09uMYgfENNeNE5eS7EVGMSbzoGqaHzzYQTSDQzMqscAyRMOaZa3GMSP4DgWTAmOo8MPL8XTPIBusgEWKr6VYaiSxDaKzmeOEQv3MYgfliNfeHWAe0oLqx4fnve39IQ5Q/yqDAEhPodXf8USW9vu6yPb9T7xg0ofBh/0PjIF@rKAqPDPAZwHcxi4imH/ex70Rjr5@RaD@JHm6yOJbd87zwU59dqx9ME0qYLselDrHfDTe1hEudnlobaMer67YWZpFBQV0Es3lIvzBs7OOt7JoBNKhkUEPIP5fz8lf1Cg//07JJH4AZfTeTOK@gCu8d0Ghb2AfkFeBdyH4oPImPqDY08AyHyFZHd3EokfqpjBVy5gnBwg3fJmygZPX0RHlQOvcy1nnzDJX6aL8uIv8x2Br7YYc/5hURV@abxl4IsWCgkYvCYb2nJ6gL91NWfB3/y0cv4V@c3ZK7tZcCR@JL9Mf@vACOw0UB7UD3xUtthkcSDi2JftXF7f2E7mo30@5vsfvO5x3fEhYKcqWIxTKMxkkGwAFNCljnm3du/@mhAg4r5fYpzeNLFBqEpt5G0fZLPJnYywvkiiOFagN53aVN49mF793C7GxI@AKppXRiFDa9TqeMUF@xM5Q0FiePkHEBE/u2e3AGDf5pnSN7sYEz/sHCJFcJrjpJGjrsbpS46ARvQir4XKzkdd5IRLWgqyLcbUH3zRAqYfxpATzDzQ7M0COoK1TBTfMdLE0/sfwETN2eXTK/f27xhF4ocf@OKe6KkD7xY4KYtw8YxGxqOQb9TJjy6wOl/@j06O078ktDiMkhEFDAuiQhZS41tBeF50BzsIIuXc4cPd41e@ee9c@ryfw7GGQpKxc7IGWOtt3mNwcGCnPOM7RvL@n/M@nXcXULnbO0Zx6o9KRm0oqjbw@4l6NvqSsRjDAwbzQrPibP@P8@x1NHXmcB2J@LEM6LdFK3jqAuRRhEb45Eo9gXQ2WDmoXbWdy/WJiBzlqC0G8QOGXtF9AvdMQLFGRIP1ABwrWBFLuoFfpXbIWzpOnv/tmjy5zU@TnpwdeX/FmVx3HVoUhQk3iar3HAg7mAfj@@YJr977lJh8i@W@xZj3L4WCo1gOGWG@tMHik0@caMH@6MK5m4/rXq6tcwesYn//kogfsfGKcNBIFqjBBO4UcFBQACnzdQlHwb29D7MOct8elxd/3L0Pk4gfPnq@QIcNLSxpYyATewbCo9PQNJW3fRnKQvx7DrfMfA3tvXPxU/MDdAI2w8qiux4cjfH9lgpVuvA2E@VBXXjw9hDZ/9zHIH5kvrM2JmFazig1SqN2RanJ9@kCvHdNbcfZB1uM5/sYU3@s86MBmFCoFFeA6ypDRSRrGgfkcIxl2J03vc0/PvsX/txipImFnCxwXFBx1mgQHJOiZchDs4cqFrOEHUeJ6Rp4OJtOTnm@68R3G7TmVUMCjhUI/zLvQQeSsixd0xOi9/tnTz5Y3/y49p4nTCt@0GJXFBU8IiSyymDIzHmXcUiF59zBwA2J@/KMkY8Y5rsf5PH6eItB/EBdwwQW9FfkqyKVZzDI3tBpjXqdN@zzrvEUem03YDvMB/EjJ3wT9gN@gW4gv4Buck2IRpJJQIb1Rx6fd41nfuH7F/f/@uv/AQ)

Comment: You know what, I'll admit that this code golf challenge wasn't as clever as I thought it was. Bubblegum stomps this challenge, so I'll give it to you. (There's probably more score to be had in compressing with LZMA rather than DEFLATE, but that's beside the point.)

Answer (score 3):

## C, 50 + 3008 = 3058 bytes

I've tried out several simple compression methods, and found that outputting the UTF-16 input (trailing newline removed) directly is the best way. Input from stdin.

```cpp
int b[999];main(){read(0,b,3008);write(1,b,3008);}
```

## Python 3, 62 + 2145 = 2207 bytes

Evil built-in. Input filename is `A`, which is an xz-compressed file of UTF-16 version.

```py
import lzma
print(lzma.open('A','rt',encoding='utf16').read())
```

Compressor code:

```py
import lzma
open('A','wb').write(lzma.compress(open('utf16_file.txt','rb').read(),lzma.FORMAT_ALONE))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 3640 (127 + 3513) bytes

```java
import java.nio.file.*;v->{Files.lines(Paths.get("a")).map(x->x.length()>1?x+"。":x).forEach(System.out::println);}
```

The total byte-length of the original file is `4003` bytes. When we remove all trailing spaces and the trailing new-line, this becomes `3888` bytes. All the lines in the file except for the single digits end with `。`, so removing all those and using `.map(x->x.length()>1?x+"。":x)` will save an additional `390` bytes.

Can definitely be golfed by just using an encoding/decoding compressed strategy, but whatever..

**Explanation:**

```java
import java.nio.file.*;        // Required import for Files and Paths

v->{                           // Method with empty unused parameter and no return-type
  Files.lines(Paths.get("a"))  //  Read the file as a String-Stream
       .map(x->                //  Map over the lines:
         x.length()>1?         //   If the length of a line is larger than 1:
          x+"。"               //    Use the line + literal "。"
         :                     //   Else:
          x)                   //    Use the line as is
       .forEach(System.out::println);
                               //  And print each of those mapped lines
}                              // End of method
```

Comment: You can try to download the file directly (maybe Ctrl+S on browsers) instead of copy-and-paste.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2605 bytes

```
•!…мOÂ6м’ZÖ₁-Pr@½õθ₃žв∊}`?(Ć·Ò[Íš2мö$qjõaF“;<!S¤mC†&ζΓ{ãˆFiUM’^Nm…M¾g¹Ć"ú¥/ÐòvÂqŒ4©Ù
1£v4ÒÀÌçтΛ˜þ∍ãÛ[£FàΔт÷¾ÜʒÕā“q¾^|°7δ«à÷³þ§I₁˜ýΣŽê¾мΘà¹œb₅γ*Üã“öÚŸEà/‚µá¢—₃;œýLº₅fK“ÎIF‹{Æ~3âтü!ï^:¢Σιв¾¢ißŠk¥´∍Õ'ÀºζE×*ÆAÄj`î¦ûKλL&н"ĀÛĀ™ú¥ÖµвrÁD²āh—ζŒ%ÇxÃ²©¼Á¹Ù½Θ¾~‹¡¨FÞFg≠¨É÷ƒá_:§£Ãìć˜ùÍ´zεΘoиXhδ'úEÐÂÖ&Ô!¨ú¹Òó²˜OOäê₃\å`q[í ₆ΣuÍ¯¬ª₆-éßkEšxX¸ï.c‰ó€‡Kð"P[áìαλ€!f¨в≠ΣYí-ʒ{€0à51QÃè…Wöù·t8ÁÏ=U—–TòΩá¨y2˜z)@¥¹#lLP¬ÔO2ýÀòŒÍä∞Δk¿cÅŒã’[ºнe¬7¢UÙÈδ´'§ÀbMÞи@Q)Vα#*yÚì°®Š₂ªl@ƶÅ∞è‡¾V@ÁçĀoµ¯ˆåÀÓ£öWg1^Kåα³¿ζ™¯í¥‰®6ê¥AïƶTCR´"zêÛ^Äª;¥n₁*ŠäδÓ₂¡Ž²Áü,|tWR¨cd¢ú×λ>B¯ÃÈÒĆâŸÎŠ˜`ΛαPиĆ₂è9×)≠ç÷ºÀ‰ÆÒ—\|<RõéÅΛ₆¢µV¿ǝâÀë7q{Σ₄Ib éZrγ)αI¸Ñ-,E½Ó´¢å7Ö8-»CʒEā%eo
³tX1s–O∞d‚÷θT3†&ïÕ)Z¯н¾½røδ¦ÎÉη~ΩSëÞÓ¿w ∍Ð¿´6тв₂M~šÜKž×Ä¦ãÅšÓ3Ýàlá|å₃м_mCs©¥¾²Á[6À3{MÍO<‡
∍9¹eΩ(ǝPΔнÅZp“=1GÂbÏΛηñzÒ²ûζœÉ‹ön®œ¦ΛÞ0®ζï₄Þ>c¬ˆ~Θ*¤_é¨ÉBÔÕð₅€xÁIz‚æ(»'JRúÓd±^pÜ±λLα½‹FΔò(ΔÆrð6±/^н₅yì}ž6îEy…´θ2s25þÔô[>Å£и¬?Òd Ñ?`Ÿ∊Xlêx`:ŠòΘBŠ':´KM^нΓæ±s»∍vǝλà"‘ív32É»‚}@ÎÈé₃I¨zA³ÚÅb≠†ËØΘÙ¹Ý²ćÛ^fǝäÚ_™§Ô©₆Θeñ¼-иx(„àR—ÑWú/”.”OKéŽÎ‘™þÊð
N/8sØ§«ÀMÂηjIĆ2*bηǝ±m¨¬¾ΔtÃ_∍ÿþΩ¼∊÷γ½.,ÙC¯¤àÊhŠ[ˆñтúΓiƒ¯[~ηΛ₆¿–©µΩJ‹»\≠:°ù…нYĀì—!Ûl1™Ö¤°´A3-мćÞôîΣFÊ)Oƶ€lª®mĀ!%½ŽZdUºĆåùÛCp±?99äƒ\ñ£ÕH´¹0f±Q2Íö’Ćв₂ǝÔ§üñ&ÔÎèçÆw¦â«×ý'Ë₃ʒвƵ
nAä„ÐĆs<F×¿4dxç©ù‹ʒóTË)¡≠{ùO5₅ʒ@
Ö…U²&¨®lŽuu“≠¹ÍÒWZâÃ¶_Ûyt‰ΛuItÃλfŒ3Ž¨Ƶ}+â©¨ƶ—*Ê1и≠ž]ˆÛ$?ʒu¾2z>ôÿÚ¤ÄŸE₁Uò!Ƶf1A1ζ‹Öj:¸Zc2Ã^d_¾₂Í%l"jÊ˜ð„.tþì∊Γ*WÛÓ™§ÜÁŒÁòz‘Σ·kçŽ>Ï~ÕÃn\β8δ₄XMe¹Ú‰.$ƒ=ÏÕ…¡˜bH5¼pñвÆÉ×¬~ßιÀP$WÆñ;Uðè‰#uú‡Ï²т?¢þ»ÂÈÑÛ@Úć‰f0Èö₅Í°¼0₆õòÿ∍ª¢ÈUTà’æÊöü₆ÉIмΛú:Σ£…Ç×ÜBÂµãÓq₃¡н¸‰4œÞª(∊ΓÍ[εS_?ì…KнâOùFr½³ê∍*θ§€‘PÄ¾õÔ ªÃΔ”Duï¿Ćub¨Λé3ìCð6µK=Çθ>wjñ‰yP¦
gr¸N(Ô½G>“aóÀo»³{Î§_øā(¢*´ΓyĀí´R§æÀ0$MÔˆζÜÊàx¸Û₁¨и"+ƶÑǝtJ”É‹Mçò‘tývÓ^:¡Ü‘≠OË!θÃw₂î(∍‘Pœ²ižraïΓ]E∞zo5θè@[žĀS4€jU≠ÃZD*Ðùв†ù·Λ{’₃≠„αûΣT3Ì×¯OS¤T–Œþ&ÞVKV.∍2§Gú₃₁~ª¼)(ø><q₂¤S»þìAMв+ U’Íy†p×E0‚QÛ£Ü–½7=nyÚ˜qú6;Δ“Ì¹YĀ—p₅!Ω"a–|á&†ª“ëkBQöã}3
s××ĀΓ¶ü¸†¹è¹zÒć†@+2ΓRαÃðû∊$º–„Ÿã>\>|d£Ýõõdʒhû#“IƒvJýi{Ùʒ₃-±¥)—ÝÅн{Š\e∞‡Δ-8¹ûÌâ₃±
«ãÜ‹›tdÂ«W"Ô£&₄;åL à¿мÂλÌм£«н₆¹NóüQH„w¦ºÔòcΔ¡HáÕ¢δĆShΔÈÔBX`Â´0₃iè«®°—fS$×ǝ&Ë3nH]wÂß0µ∍±ò+ÚΓqQ]õºćuH~°ÄÜÉ’=øƶË₄¹\ï≠7ðDg›½ÑšƵ÷é3µÿη–|Øìä₄CĀ²‹₅So–saÆ₃¦õÌÉr—=0ć₆?ŸÛÏƶ‡[õ¸β%H<-çмlÞ„‹59°C>#ÓΛh₂µJôü…ι¥mΩ«ÎP`§т·¥Òž©Ó¤½θVC!’вxjí<:∍{ÇS&PsÆÅË†:₄Ì¡ˆΛð∍ó«:ièîðÕ{ôт%F¨2uÞ∍ù)/θÙ-αŒj)7·BÿJ€Ãδñ«[éÒm‡ìõиà₁AVw₆ÇÇÂk“Ÿkˆ£}TžŽ¹©¤âò+gZεê}ñÖàΔ÷ǝ³U;°:ûhmÑòÏÜ₄[ÛÁçû$µ“"Xz€‚zλ1
¯0ï3ƶTн=íõ99ƒñβÌõöæ¶E˜ƵÝÑŒà·ƒFÊVùûèÏWŒþā4αº+ŒÔFàŽrÆ#'€î²d¸xLmAĀ÷«vV°©!¯āÌØ≠в'ÕxêÃÄmWβªŸíê¢6}2ú…åô%gÿEXÙr6íËÛ€¶Ý₄·®₄¬ºó«'(Ë—ûá—ÔË½*e‚*Õ›Ø/"‘¡oαΛñ†4~¸qCyî>òšqu"₆Æ¡áë“¤š_¦¦!т<gÙ×¼'oθp²n¶'^±‚X!½ƶΔ>{is¢λ"oAÁjв₄z‹ø₆)5HˆCÍ‘˜Þðêβƶÿùc¼λoM₄ªÞΛ≠H&ÚþýoÒÝ¥@a³Y[áæ°$¢}ćĆ¹±»₂¥˜³²™Lm9GΘΣΛ«2‚O»‘ηhĀÛˆ\¥ηÕÞ ‘6Rm‹ð≠~r–[+“Å7Àx/т÷âIι”Õ¾õ'3K[]=€Q}Ô,XÖè₁3µ /ÖZ₄X
≠è₁÷
≠Rèxž×hÉÑ’₁óqÊÒ:<eÀÙØãÚžNg‹Ā~Gη«ø¶`rΣÖ)Ä«Ω.Ç<Æ;´(…;±+§AP™wQÉι×¶т+_Ωj-Ê°ƒ§¡çóùÿ‡αØAh—“ζì(Adß¾y‚2ÿÄyFìεíøíagúÐ₂¥¼MsÀïê;EAŠ+³ìΘEwC–Hç•5ôçTô»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JVdnU5NbF/3OrxBU6kUpVlQEuaCICBbUKyoWVEQRAVEEZUKAINZrEqQkYELoIJCQQEIKM3slOCMzZ@JfyB@57zq8Y0GfPDlnl1X2zjl8737uw//@SxgmkxOGmXioCsYj8VDCMHoT3xPGnuzq1iIJw6f8CWNvLBL3JN5/eHf3dHrUJBsw1@JzzJkXD2F9X0sjfPfKEgb7iZPJV2SqqSRhcKSqdWXpgmvHVPakppJn3rnYxEsqJfJYAlFTCjZl@iD@hecVjC0x8yGZx2hSrrheHYIZBnzC7B@jsu3YEUm8/wwXbLXiKoNDWf8YsSER2H@bMRTt4aUtErnzVlaPKq8swsEP1xCR2XImwG@HlSsWxoJE4iE1AocEYpb7CWO/WsuEHS5@G@sYi/lL4TiYMIyJD06ZTBisTPhEzILwBdnk248q9ItfyplioAum7nxMMopQMlbuFMikcqlA3CMRmXyCHzHHU5kWr455KA0G2VTrpRjOhKkYfY13sSwzCFao4IXUeDglaoAtakj0Tepa4Lv44p5W9PwtnmhPA2NQ6zHzfgx0oFc8Mi8h9EgAoxJWIxLpZiTilLkyTJQ9Tgw6ZA6D2Ng2w1lXILPiQi@WogPMP4DP4u1UPjXSHPffaFDeNGyWsuxGfE@FNZnf2@SpZqyJZ8deVYUpLDD3W5i@21KLn3sSRpNytfOMFVkSfmLKxjx@PC2NOTtuiB8rBx4kDKtYSxiXEgZnBVZTqmvhxJJyqyCfJT@SOaJm0KFc/@Bn9m9zFx/mwHE49xIDnCMcrrP8Adl4eQw9@HqqRlfeYLkKj5pnI@be5O3YOzOKWNDA3mcXqmUJ1qo8hAkPT8yMz5hKvJ9Q1qey9QD9fMB2jtbKZjz8UJaOymQNRvGeoPCmySwM9ysxEfcXXcq4ptx7M99gDEuyKssxR8JolIVnRdvr6OdxOiqnRK4VMaDZqKFZfLKyY8I077SwrOvXH@feqcC0csuabKl1Nk9W8FOmWQZZPkKgTRdjZXv9asll8aZ0YgG2O@iThRMy/ZyAzIw5MKW8sOhLnbGweHhN6K@3L69flrkH9UIkYFgFC8/w0F68hzlqwmTMjy8xx479rrIpd3XcHzXx25g7juEMlhazRPwmDLoPJphZwVtvT16Gj33qVzZ2TCbFd022fo1jkkksHm3pUq6Esa/8/h7M32xVaxnKXc5Wfsv@q5Rkt4iXUUwfxfdj2RIs@W0ujfbsf9icJGsvb@S2sTlVLFI9qYIN5b@ar4mOFQxl3JSVeJgcCLfCz5rP4AsG1Ua3mr@CRUzw2K3XezQp/pUt8R75YyQsjMbK7pgT9opYBMMs0gxZ3s8HlnyMw/EMzreYJhbjobqmkjYSYJrHs161R2DI76rE56qTbFUSDz0ugYdqPv3XeLWyxsPov/mCdD2VexbG@/jKom3A3QkzvxskpSwYJHew/py9t8iMsmEiR5bVOlZYFEwUPpClHVO3GsmUqTrMa16dgRVDWKUOEL0d6Cnv1OnPpEsw7fxlNsxSL@47L2AXgv4CgRHm@WXKCk86/zK1YvWIuA/eiYd5wBssvYtFjmC59A3BL17lz2vLO4wIb/DWFqJfXHG/LJ2GuX4Pvp2@G/NTcW88w0LH3QIix6NGzsQcaQXirajkecqCGXG3SZAlePVrXAXhSEkYRvDzVX4eBvnYMPauiH14j3mWsVzmOospjWPov0/YsHH4iBFq4ij5P07NGSBUHxElUxir07CehVXmNf9HHsItoey4vyM9YZiA4zIxhm/XsUnFHD/AP1UVmKfIfuHlWswi@IDVpIsHj7VhhFq0CEMljGqjsTxqysu8rzZ@jYu7SeYoKBFlfYneOo2LLUQUNY75ElhrEj7wF0ZLqDpTVPQPDTFHLUnopuhuKsuTbbOs1Harjf/De4ugJDp8av68FsXgLWZXIKsIaEsL/0ORpTZZk2F7lquj@y5T5L23OD87HmLOE/BiWdFZPmRUba@zwc9kQZaboobk/RKOhW/W18hmVPM/AFvJC3GfPn4cU9vmWyyJC0PnyJZAziNxX8qjHK1Tf6KmXWSzjlZWMAQ3VZY9mCNNTa8J8UnWYxjhNHxkT36b455tX9LzYioZK/tv1NR2sgzDsnWovgOzdETmEKDPrV3FxwxxMrEuBKoOE0i/zUVJ9GjDTI14UlnL5WexcHs7Ya@9gJoP8/Wb5HuvrNfB9uYlxUHZ2stZbBV8FDPnU3nmtn3vshgOIc68DdZMfMiN@/n1WOQ2a23bd/q3uV0ieZ2FrNAWxtiJPvokRawGnuRt36Pc4lzqH6n0vbFA/Dcf5KH3Tn2dRLQ4fd7/LKURH@g/q0zswEtiYomtVZbM67BR/XbhZUcPRbsHHvJpRLlk4ylmY@FCfO0m3Xqf31KeY8pLUt6ofMiUxpjDgX3b5lP4iiFNHueO/f65wxJ6AXfcQ@kbZOGWuvFDBWCo3nedT9wnarCqBX11bzs2KRb4Kp4/xtMUuIgEaYHv8Q22IoxFB/jOoxz@nwjop9utSiiH2KKKerBFeBITk3hfcxXkzShmCPB1hPQLg@WcK2zYLGD8tJ8ZDLC79jMwcpJwwdLCJouTwujnBYeoPROykL5bCHyuVb4rdac1OGcqqFqTVQiUtUqYFF3gjZnKL7O7tjpSTW2MMBTrHllgA@mQ43@3Y0W2oqb2@zLH6@fzsVSidcZXcQoDyl/4uhFu3vimWmaSHreK/2I64Rg@W0iA3MMaaGtBWevCF5mtgz/aky6TmRQjyxuS5ad4L7M5MzDk7KuEdcdEabQzYUcHTYKE66Gl@1OyaJfffo2/JOXGdwW1kgD3MNiXCL@ChWMRhV3rwaCjCh@TlR@9rzUwlpn9Z50TtdfzJBZpvYcVZbldSlPpbD7M1@aKamORqOHKIebeWKP9rffm35kcWDhiac3isKBsXewCK7srYxPKTV13Xc3nyDgsK1WcP69SEYisSComrlVcO8Ab82T2LBHArxh7utnMUEY6/IUnW7QNT10hFojP4sq4J2tPjW7wZ6qz4wWGS3OooZdgI9XtWmXCR0895@SwY2/B5pETuhN2fJIANYYEekHoJKv5lHt88y2cqTyCExPfWHx65hLx4nqXn9RGdAxHDcoixI8GhSbrnARoTxqDjqKsPGW5zIx6CVzq@od9nD8NFmbJIcBVeKvwbT1jGScYfPW/zQ0I7uUF5dvmV@cRftKF0d9m5pgtbpnO0CI9jv54uCvmuPWQ9SX@lTX7GC8MslSTGpnuJKrRbm4Ums2X9YTt4vUUQsWVSt6dwPSFPRyZtzjjG@kun@IhccmiNjKTBC4SR6FL5xgaZY0DCP3ugbKK8xznvyEOxd6o6UoDDfA9rGdu3OXJXjKq9wmzXZRloSxYH13Zh@Ff46n4mP/83O3X5OOPHPFptrnhycKYsrRcug0f9Xeg/Vw3Fb2PQCTWRk/BT/hRQPskcIu@Peg4itW/HzMFDjDfYs5tHzbICVJwS23sdmMES5RYY19J1CAena2x/0ozP2m7B5MuxAwr@gmDrYzqVA47YTSdZsFt@Kql0VnLIPzKs//cyWzMxkPPwFryd@DwcVktKdwLi7I1aCT5zlMquT7NqIBMN9HOFvGl@q5wkZENDvjmWISSbqH/hJX/WglXrtG4p6MRP08WMOkuDFxJrW6jbPUzNYOjQI8jn6hyJhJ8VVvkmiwWsH5YJjaGuuD9Y9xfJnN57QyHnwYyDpI@o9nKHTM3ZhyVjTPYOk8SUTG8NKvFWg6E5iYtgkvwxf1UMmNP8bXXWsQG@Mv4lEiK@Z/umMT17mosQocI0BumaCKerMc3lQ8L7@DGd72BQVv4Ws0JWS1AsKGJIuqhKNsZcC1rxrkZwX1spMGecqNzV8LGOlUwN0lWcrCSz9k4Hj6Fn/AdP859xa08rLyP/JiR9dIdO3s3zh6aiTuuM7Tla9CAncPX65rS0Z5DnLA2s/hvK7fBGMdN0940neayeOrF33GhqZgitiGLr65RxeeTZSXawwu0EMU9aRjq4Ejei76m68ojC@zxT47sk0fe5Wl/mKHNe/c/xlbpDYy2HuFnH7XiLZGs4xpsG7KsfywR7exFWrruk5XBOfUPKz5KOPMhk83U/rSJkYN6GhNnM5chm5Zjx6Fu8beUvMFyIfcXZ0t7ii6@iUrpxCKrJVMxZx25NJP8x3jyMZeXYQmlNSv/C/E8l/W0O8Izxm4kS3h7XVkLu560kWXBlOZi9DTqmaOvU5sxV3VTxuFzO6YSaJ2lA08QLgvKQ8ZsIfBAQirYXKnTWMAEB6hBx7lUzoQRhJu5BY7LdNE9WftHL3EzsrpPJt9FB7juBygpQQ3x6R07Fx8PDfxC0/GziratbLKYx8Cq9MA5ojYa9Fa7Y7ol05y7hzCxh0@PXG7Ssa3ytm5yzFKbpXWx/ygMHQf1Oo/JchXQTjKkjS4tv6L29inW/dI7WP@6QczNEauk856D@H5TDwRJ2hf0Q2zof17GXIfeIRo4A3zbtYYerLXQs8wFJx9y5xkl/13c8iMXqRGBqKH7rCJA4Jf1u63Khe8ZNNhFNX8AAydhOiFejrkzJ8SdJbPF1cz09SWuMgF2Y/2PMatOzTdm44OscgidZetmKYMBzggUVzdGiht2N1g7PXMpvbgePyRCKxnLY@n73pRxL/YRVATdvcfcG/7dLaiEKtsY4woWTpQWxxxZ9P8lNVL6uoR1OofZhGHyMFVl9iq8Evzvv/8B)

---

*Shrugs in 05AB1E: I'm astonished how direct base conversion almost ties BG...*